# How can I call a CSS animation on a nested element within a parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm looking to remove a class from a nested div element upon focus of the parent. Then I want to replace the class with another that has a CSS animation that will autoplay. I'm looking to do this within multiple elements in the same class as well so it will need to be able to handle more than one. I'm not sure what to do as I've kind of reached to where I believe I should be at this point but to no avail.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>title</title>
</head>
<style>

<style>

  div {
  filter: opacity(0%);
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.noGrow {

}

.grow {
  animation-name: derp;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  filter: opacity(100%);
}

@keyframes derp {
  from{width: 0px;}
    to{width: 300px;}

}

</style>

<body>
<span id="divHolder" tabindex="1">
<div class="noGrow firstDiv">
</div>
</span>


</body>
<script src="jquery.js"> </script>
<script>

var divHolder = $(".divHolder");
var firstDiv = $(".firsDiv");

divHolder.focus(function () {
  if($(".firstDiv").hasClass("noGrow")){
    $(this).removeClass("noGrow");
    $(this).addClass("grow");
    console.log("It's working.");
  }
});

</script>

</html>
```

Thank you for any and all help. It is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please explain more about the issue, I see this code working as expected

Comment: You don't need to add/remove the `noGrow` class since it has no functional purpose...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, these two lines seem to be the problem:

```
 $(this).removeClass("noGrow");
 $(this).addClass("grow");
```

$(this) refers to the divHolder element you are binding the focus event to. If you want to change the class of firstDiv, you'll need to change the lines to this:

```
firstDiv.removeClass('noGrow');
firstDiv.addClass('grow');
```

However, based on your CSS, I would suggest using toggleClass, and leaving the noGrow class off completely. Your div becomes:

```
<div class="firstDiv"></div>
```

and your JS becomes:

```
divHolder.focus(function () {
    firstDiv.toggleClass('grow');
    console.log('growing!');
});
```

Finally, if you don't know where in the list of descendants your 'growable' div will be, you can use something like find():

```
divHolder.focus(function(){
    $(this).find('div').toggleClass('grow');
    // if the div is given an id like #growable we can do this:
    // $(this).find('#growable').toggleClass('grow');
});
```

Comment: There were a few errors on my part in how I typed this out but that worked Cruiser! Thanks so much.